# Cannot convert IWebElement to IWebElement after updating selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have just updated my selenium from `2.29.1` to `2.35`, and now I am getting some riddiculous error messages when I try to compile my application:

First error:

> cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement [c:\my_project_path\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.2.35.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll]'
>   to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'

Second error:

> The type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WebDriver,
>   Version=2.31.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.

How do I solve this?

PS. I already have reference to `WebDriver.dll` in my project (which contains IWebElement)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, we can close it now. I solved it, there was one old reference which nuget update didn't find, so I had to manually reinstall it. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue and my exact issue was I updated webdriver in 1 project of my solution and not both projects. In the NuGet manager (VS 2015) there is a "Consolidate" menu option after the Browse, Installed, Updates ones. On that tab, I was able to update references in both of my projects.